# Camera preview problem on Nexus S while implementing MediaRecorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder, nexus-s

I am recording video using MediaRecorder and also using SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder for previewing the video. Everything works fine on HTC Legend with Android 2.2 but the preview is not shown on Nexus S with Android 2.3.4, instead just the black screen is shown.
Following are my code snippets:
 For MediaRecorder:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem?

Comment: same issue here too....and the video quality also not good..

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same issue.  If you use one of CamcorderProfiles, it'll work.  But if you attempt to set the settings yourself, there's many combinations that don't work, and just a few that do.

If you want to set the settings yourself, start off with the same settings as one of the profile, and then see which tweaks you're doing are causing it to break.

Answer (score 0):

I think I saw somewhere that camera.unlock(); recorder.setCamera(camera)l should be asap after creating recorder. And then after that all the other setup things can be done. Be sure to follow correct setup order described in Android camera manual.